# what is best subwoofer for the genelec 8030b speakers?

Tags: speakers, home-studio

I want to buy the Genelec 8030B speakers. But most reviews tell me the bass is a bit underwelming. So many suggested buying a subwoofer... I thought of buying a genelec subwoofer, but there 2 subwoofers genelec offers and i dont know what subwoofer would fit my needs best and what the differences are the between the 7050B and the 7040A subwoofers from genelec?

best thomas :)

Answer (score -1):

JBL All the way. Known for their response, punch and power capacity. Their made for high end bass delivery.

Comment: How do these compare to the two speakers that the OP is specifically asking about?  Which particular models would pair well with the tweeter they are looking at?  Currently this doesn't really answer the OP's question.